# How to cancel the callback url registered on blockchain.info

Tags: blockchain.info

So i was testing the Blockchain receive API, and during the first trial, I had a typo on the callback url.

Does that mean blockchain.info will retry to call that bad url 1000 times before it finally gives up ?

Is there a way to cancel the unwanted callback registered on blockchain.info ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does that mean blockchain.info will retry to call that bad url 1000 times before it finally gives up ?

It would appear so, and I can't see a way to cancel it, besides creating a page at that url with the text '*ok*'

To see what requests it's made already, try looking at [this page](https://blockchain.info/api/api_receive) and putting the bad url in the Check Callback Response Log form.

Comment: Too bad It was domain name typo.